# pandas convert mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm to date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the time column in a df

```
accrual_time_x
1/4/19 20:32
```

trying to convert into

```
%m/%d/%y

df["accrual_time_x"] = pd.to_datetime(df["accrual_time_x"],format="%m/%d/%y")
```

yet still return

```
0   2019-01-04 20:32:00
```

How could I convert into 01-04-2019? thanks!

Comment: The format does not specify how to *render* the timestamps, it specifies how to *parse* the strings.

Comment: Try pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M").dt.normalize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
df['accrual_time_x'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: It works! thank you @bruno mello